# convert UTC datetime to JST datetime in freemarker tempate

Tags: freemarker

I have requirement to convert the UTC date time to JST date time in free marker template, can any one please guide how do this.

I am using smooks with freemarker combination.

Thanks for you suggestions in advance.

Comment: Is your dateTime in a `java.util.Date` instance?  What have you tried already?  Please post the FTL that is not working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FreeMarker has a `time_zone` setting, and it automatically show Java `Date`-s in that time zone. If it's not set properly in your environment, you can force it in the template like `<#setting time_zone="JST">`, but it's kind of ugly to do.

If that UTC date-time comes in a string, then first you have to tell FreeMarker to parse that string as a date-time with something like `myUTCDate?datetime('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`; I can't know what what's the exact pattern in your case. But if it doesn't include the time zone, then you have a bit of trouble here, as it will be interpreted in the `JST` timezone. In that case you could do `(myUTCDate + ' UTC')?datetime('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z')`. And of course if you do this a lot, you better put this mess into a `#function`.

**Update:**
There was a mistake in my original answer: it has used `hh` that means 0-12 hours without `a`. I have changed that to `HH`, which is 0-23 hours. Also here's a tests I did. Works fine for me:

```
<#setting time_zone='JST'>
<#setting datetime_format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'>

Current time (Java Date object):
Local time non-ISO: ${.now}
UTC ISO: ${.now?iso_utc}
Local ISO: ${.now?iso_local}
Local ISO without zone: ${.now?iso_local_nz}

<#assign myUTCDate = '2010-05-15 10:00:00'>
Interperted as local, printed as local: ${myUTCDate?datetime}
Interperted as UTC, printed as local: ${(myUTCDate + ' UTC')?datetime('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z')}
```

which prints:

```
Current time (Java Date object):
Local time non-ISO: 2013-11-10 01:34:00
UTC ISO: 2013-11-09T16:34:00Z
Local ISO: 2013-11-10T01:34:00+09:00
Local ISO without zone: 2013-11-10T01:34:00

Interperted as local, printed as local: 2010-05-15 10:00:00
Interperted as UTC, printed as local: 2010-05-15 19:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has an entire section devoted to dates and functions for iso_ http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html

However, the documentation does not refer to the fact that you can chain the methods together. Even though this is implicit with freemarker. For example:

"2013-11-09T16:34:00Z"?datetime?iso_local which takes a string in UTC date converts it to datetime and then prints out with the local settings.